# Gaps in table boundaries

Tags: tables, border

I am using [**tablesgenerator**](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/#) to generate tables, and the effect is not bad. But there are some flaws. For example, there is a gap at the corner of the boundary of the table.
[image]

And the border thickness does not keep the same thickness. Is there a good solution to modify the generated latex codes from tablesgenerator?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{clll}
        & a                     & b                     & c                    \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that tablesgenerator comes up quite often it makes tabular that are vastly over complicated, you could remove _every one_ of those `multicolumn`   Is using it really easier than just writing the latex directly? You could use the hhline package to get a rule without that notch although most tables look better without the vertical rules.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks but sorry. Could you please give some more specific suggestions for  hhline ? I'm not sure how to fix the gap or the size of the border. I'm still a novice at making tables with latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is : load the package `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{clll}
        & a                     & b                     & c                    \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, there is other ways to create your table. Here is an example with `nicematrix` (which, in particular, loads `array`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[first-row,first-col,hvlines]
        & a & b & c \\
      1 \\
      2 \\
      3 \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Thank you! Your previous code ensured that the gap in the bottom right was filled, but the problem in the bottom left remained. And the second piece of code failed to run in texlive2020 on my computer. (Error: Environment NiceTabular undefined. \begin{NiceTabular})

Comment: @licheng: You are right. The package `array` solves the problem only for the bottom right corner. For the code with `nicematrix`, I think that you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation.

Comment: Remark if you use Overleaf. Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. 
I am going to download the latest version.